# How can I use generated graphql operations when using AWS_LAMBDA auth mode in my Amplify Angular project?

Tags: angular, graphql, aws-amplify

using AWS Amplify and Angular, can't use generated graphql operations when using auth mode AWS_LAMBDA

when using regular auth mode, I used to use:

```
this.api.getForm();
```

and it worked great, but now I've added AWS_LAMBDA auth mode
and this approach is not working anymore since I need to append an auth Token to the request.
is there a way to 'store' the token globally and configure it to be sent with each request?
so far I've found:

```
const formQueryResult: any = await API.graphql({
      query: this.getFormQueryOperation,
      variables: { id: this.formId },
      authMode: 'AWS_LAMBDA',
      authToken: this.authToken,
    });
```

and it's working, but I have to write the graphql operation manually since I haven't managed to import it.
any idea how to store the token so I can use the shorter operation, or to import the operation?